# Trying to stress test hard drive, but windows shows no hard drive usage during read

Tags: c#, windows

I am trying to write a simple program to stress test a hard drive, however, when I watch hard drive usage in resmon.exe and the Task Manager in Windows it shows no hard drive usage while the read is happening.

Currently I am writing 10GB of random bytes to a file as fast as possible to write test it. Then I am reading that file 512KB bytes at a time as quickly as I can. The goal is to try to max out the hard drives read capabilities.

The code I am using to read is below. My first thought is maybe it is just optimizing away the reads. So I was summing the values of the bytes in the buffer and taking the average. This makes the process take way longer, but I still see no usage in the Task Manager or in resmon.exe.

I'm sure I am missing something obvious here, but I am not sure what the problem is. I know there is a file system cache, but surely that won't affect reading through a 10GB file?

```
            IProgress<double> progress = new Progress<double>( ( pct ) => Console.WriteLine( pct ) );

            var fi = new FileInfo("E:\\temp\\out");

            var size = fi.Length * 1;

            using var stream = new FileStream( fi.FullName, FileMode.Open );
            var curRead = 0;
            var readBuffer = new byte[1024*512];
            var j = 0;
            long totalRead = 0;

            var numReads = Math.Floor( size / (double) readBuffer.Length );
            var reportWait = Math.Floor( numReads / 100 );

            while ( totalRead < size )
            {
                curRead = stream.Read( readBuffer, 0, readBuffer.Length );

                if ( curRead < readBuffer.Length )
                {
                    stream.Position = 0;
                }
                totalRead += curRead;

                if ( j % reportWait == 0 )
                {
                    progress.Report( (totalRead / (double)size) * 100 );
                }

                j++;
            }
```

Comment: Are you sure the file is full of random data? For example, reading an empty sparse file doesn't require any I/O for obvious reasons. Oh, and use `long` variables when dealing with file indices and sizes - probably not the problem here, but still.

Comment: @Luaan Yeah, it is reading a file that was created by repeatedly writing a buffer that was filled by Random.Next(byte[]). I've also checked the contents and it is definitely full of random bytes. I also tried compressing it just to make sure and it is incompressible.

Comment: This type of software is typically written in native code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, your code works fine. The problem is you're *severely* underestimating how much caching is going on!

The first time I run your code, I get exactly the results you expect - steady 5 GiB/s reads. Repeating the run results in *zero* reads. The whole file is cached in memory, and will stay there until there's something else that needs that cache - which is unlikely while you keep running your benchmark over and over.

10 GiB just isn't a large enough file nowadays. I can't find disk cache size in my drive specs, but even just the caching done by Windows 10 on my machine is enough to give me 30 GiB of files permanently cached in memory.

Of course, there's a simple fix - tell Windows not to do that:

```
using var stream = new FileStream(
  fi.FullName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite, 8, 
  (FileOptions)0x20000000);
```

The `FileOptions` setting (not part of the enum in .NET) says "No buffering, please!" This probably isn't respected by the disk itself (disks lie to the OS all the time), but it does get rid of the Windows-level file caching, and you'll get far more repeatable results.

Comment: This is working perfectly. I am really shocked that it will cache a whole 10GB file.

Comment: @JohnStrom The modern OS approach to caching is essentially "no point in leaving that memory unused". If any application actually needs that memory, it's available at a moment's notice - if not, it can be a ridiculous performance boost to file I/O, especially for applications that aren't particularly written with performance in mind.